# Slow TSQL query with nested selects

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written a query, but appears to run quite slowly in our live environment.
The query contains nested select statements which I believe to slow down execution.

Does anyone have any tips of how I could re-write the query to improve the execution speed.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '20140101'
SET @EndDate = '20140101'

SELECT a.applicationid,
       a.ourreference,
       (SELECT MAX(e.CreateDateTime) FROM tblEmail AS e WHERE( e.ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID) AND (ISNULL(e.StandardEmailID,0) <> 3)) AS 'LastEmail',
       (SELECT MAX(l.CreateDateTime) FROM tblLetter AS l WHERE l.ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID AND l.ExternalDocumentTypeID IS NULL) AS 'LastInternalLetter',
       (SELECT MAX(l.CreateDateTime) FROM tblLetter AS l WHERE l.ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID AND l.ExternalDocumentTypeID IS NOT NULL) AS 'LastExternalLetter'
INTO #Temp
FROM tblapplication AS a
WHERE (a.LogDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate + '23:59:59')
AND (a.BusinessSourceID NOT IN (11, 16))
AND (a.ApplicationStatusID = 100)

SELECT *
FROM #Temp AS tem
WHERE ((LastEmail < LastExternalLetter) AND (LastInternalLetter < LastExternalLetter))
```

Cheers everyone

edit- Sorry I should say what the query is for. I am trying to see if our customers have sent us a letter and we haven't responded to them with a letter/email

Comment: Please use actual execution plan, you can see there where the problem is.

Comment: I find the execution plan a bit hard to follow, I only ever really use it for finding missing indexes

Comment: From the execution plan it looks like the three things that cost the most are Hash Match: 17%, Parallelism: 11% and Index Seek (NonClustered): 18%

Comment: can you try using cte instead of temp table? I'm not sure it will work but you could try

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
(
    Select a.applicationId, a.ourreference,
           max(e.CreateDateTime) LastEmail,
           max(li.CreateDateTime) LastInternalLetter,
           max(le.CreateDateTime) LastExternalLetter
    from tblApplication a
    left outer join tblEmail e on e.ApplicationID = a.ApplicationID 
    left outer join tblLetter li on li.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId
    left outer join tblLetter le on le.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId
    WHERE (a.LogDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate + '23:59:59')
    AND (a.BusinessSourceID NOT IN (11, 16))
    AND (a.ApplicationStatusID = 100)
    and (e.StandardEmailID <> 3 or e.StandardEmailId is null)
    group by a.ApplicationId, a.OurReference
)x
WHERE ((LastEmail < LastExternalLetter) AND (LastInternalLetter < LastExternalLetter))
```

This gets rid of the temporary table. Remember, with SQL wherever you have a Table you can substitute a query (in Selects anyway). This should make it a bit more efficient, but you want to look at the Query Plans and see what's holding it up.

Cheers -

Comment: Cheers for your help, I had to change the code very slightly to get results to appear from your query.
I'm afraid it didn't run any faster

Comment: Then you need to look at the query plan! At a guess, you will need indexes on the Email and Letter tables on ApplicationId. An index on tblApplication.LogDate ,ight help as well, but see what the QEP says.